# Another random tree generator

Tags: python, graph, tree, networkx

I would like to construct a random tree: for each node, there a random number of leaves is created.

I am almost there, but I don't understand why recursion is done only at the first leaf of a branch.

This is my code:

```
# init, total_staff is the leaves counter
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_node(0)
total_staff = 0

# help function to create a group of leaves
# (the number of leaves will follow a given prob distribution)

def makeTeam():
    
    global total_staff
    
    # number of people reporting to root
    team_size = random.choices(team_population, weights = optimal_size_weight, k=1)[0]
    
    team = []
    for _ in range(team_size):
        total_staff += 1
        team_id = total_staff
        team.append(team_id)
    
    return team

# function to create a tree (representing an organisation)
def buildOrganisation(root):
    
    global total_staff
    if total_staff > 25:
        return g

    team = makeTeam()

    for team_id in team:
        print('creating sub ', root, team_id, team)
        g.add_edge(root, team_id)
        buildOrganisation(team_id) # this is the point I don't get: I expect recursion to be done for each team_id...
    
    return g
```

The result I have, though, is this:
note that recursion is only at the first node of each branch, instead I want it for all nodes of the each branch.

[image]

Can you help me fix it and understand why ?

Comment: There is this part in your code: `if total_staff > 25: return g`. If you want to limit the depth of the tree that's the wrong approach. You limit the number of total nodes.

Comment: @Matthias thank you this is what I want- I want to limit the number of total nodes, and have as many layers as it will take. My problem is that branches are only developed on one side, on one leaf of each layer, and not on all leaves.

Comment: That's the way your algorithm works. You create child nodes for the root element. Then you take the first child node and create child nodes for that on the second level. Then you take the first child node on the second level and create child nodes on the third level and so on until you reach the max number of nodes. Maybe you want to limit the number of child nodes depending on the total number of nodes you want to create.

Comment: @matthias i want to create child nodes for *each* child in a level, not just the first. I am using recursion within this cycle for : `for team_id in team: [...] buildOrganisation(team_id)`: why does it create only for the first child node at each level ? I want my algorithm to complete adding new children for each child in a level, instead of iterating down the first child of each level. Can you show a code and an explanation of why my iteration is not working in the way I thought?

Comment: @matthias - as an example: I want to first complete adding children for nodes 1 to 8, and then move down and add 1's children, 2's children .. 8's children, and on on the next level. When number of max number of children is met, the tree stops.

Comment: You have to understand recursion. In your example you call `buildOrganization` that calls `makeTeam` and `makeTeam` creates teams 1-8. Now back in `buildOrganization` you loop over the teams. You start to handle team 1 calling `buildOrganization`. Teams 2-8 will be processed when you returned from the handling of team 1. Now for team 1 you create the teams 9-17. You process team 9 first in the loop, 10-17 will be handled later (and team 2-9) even later. Now for team 9 you create 18-20, for 18 ... and so on. Then comes the time where `total_staff` is bigger than 25.

Comment: ... That's during the processing of team 26. Now you stop adding new teams, but the existing teams in the queue are still processed. You go back to 23 and add 27, but no children since the limit of max 25 was reached. Back to 21 where you add 24 and 25. Back to 18 where you add 22. Back to 9 where you add 19 and 20. Yes, you created those nodes before, but due to the nature of your algorithm (depth first) they are only processed now. Now going back to team 1 where the loop adds team 10-17 and finally back to team 0 where teams 2-8 are added in the loop.